# serverless event.body was an object but content-type is not json

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

i am using serverless to deploy my api;

```
functions:
  # hello:
  #   handler: index.handler
  #   events:
  #     - http: ANY /
  #     - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
  addAnnouncement:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: /abc/{foo}/cde/efg
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                foo: true
      - http:
          method: DELETE
          path: /abc/{foo}/cde/efg
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                foo: true
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /abc/{foo}/cde/efg
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                foo: true
```

my api routes look like this;

getting following error when i hit api-gateway-url

```
{
  "errorMessage": "event.body was an object but content-type is not json",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
  "getBody (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-http/lib/request.js:24:13)",
  "new ServerlessRequest (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-http/lib/request.js:44:18)",
  "Promise.resolve.then (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-http/serverless-http.js:30:25)",
"<anonymous>"
]
}
```

Comment: show your index.handler function code

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue with serverless-http, whenever I use `serverless invoke` (calling the API via API Gateway works normally though)